# Making pages protected in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to protect few pages to make it accessible only to authenticated users so i wonder is it a good approach to make my layout be on client or i can use a better approach to make it on server

layout.tsx

```
"use client";
import { LogOut, Profile } from "@/components";
import { SideBar } from "@/layout";
import { withAuth } from "@/utils/withAuth";
import "@/styles/main.scss";

function MainLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <SideBar />
      {children}
      <LogOut />
      <Profile />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuth(MainLayout);
```

withAuth.tsx

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import { auth } from "./firebase";

export const withAuth = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  const AuthenticatedComponent = (props: any) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          router.push("/sign-in");
        }
      });

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [router]);

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };

  return AuthenticatedComponent;
};
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example).